# RichTextFx scrolling event

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, richtextfx

Is it possible to register scrolling listener for StyleClassedTextArea (and the rest of the RichTextFx family panes) ?

Could you give me example how to do that ?

Common approach from TextArea doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 0.7M1 you can register listeners with the `estimatedScrollXProperty()` and `estimatedScrollYProperty()`. I don't know if there is a way in earlier versions.

Comment: There was no supported way in earlier versions.

Comment: @TomasMikula I tried estimatedScrollYProperty() and inserted StyleClassedTextArea into VirtualizedScrollPane. 

But estimatedScrollYProperty() is returning inconsistent numbers. 

http://pastebin.com/9EPTZXfv

Scrollbar is flickering up & down. Can this behavior be suppressed ?

Comment: @jmt is it [RichTextFX/307](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/307)?

Comment: Seems like its same/similar problem. I'm trying to download 0.7-M2 to confirm your fix. 
Unfortunately GitHub is giving me 404 error when I'm trying to download M2.

Comment: @TomasMikula I upgraded project to 0.7-M2 and scrolling is smooth. Good job ! Issue 307 is mostly gone. 

EstimatedScrollYProperty() still returning numbers which flicker little bit, but it's in order or few percent difference instead of tenth of percent which was previous case.